# dynamic alertdialog with radio buttons

Tags: android

I am trying to make the item list dynamic, so i can add to it on runtime, but i have no idea. CharSeqence isnt dynamic, and no clue how to use the adapter option, how could i change my code to be dynamic?

```
private void alertDialogLoadFile() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Choose:");  
    CharSequence[] items = { "moshe", "yosi", "ee" };
    alert.setSingleChoiceItems(m_items , -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item){
            /* User clicked on a radio button do some stuff */
        }
    });

    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    AlertDialog ad = alert.create();
    ad.show();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?  You want to have the choices be variable at runtime?  Who is deciding what the choices are?

Comment: I want them to be created on runtime, like those choices are being retrived from some database, so you cant choose which items will be in the alert dialog before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the dialog in `onCreateDialog()`, you can implement `onPrepareDialog()` to change the choices before it's displayed to the user.  For example:

```
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {    
    if (id == YOUR_DIALOG_ID) {

        // Create new adapter
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>();
        adapter.add("new items ...");
        ...

        // Use the new adapter
        AlertDialog alert = (AlertDialog) dialog;
        alert.getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

You could also get the same effect by getting the adapter from the dialog (and casting it to the correct type) and adding or removing the items as you see fit.  I'd probably lean towards simply creating a new adapter, because you won't have to worry about casting the value from `getListAdapter()` to the wrong type.  However, reusing the adapter is probably a bit more memory efficient.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(); 
you cant use it this way, there is no defualt constructor.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using a builder, try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> itensAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>();
itensAdapter.add("whatever");

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CalculatorActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Escolha uma opção");
builder.setAdapter(itensAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                removeDialog(DIALOG_AREA);
        }
    });
dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: There is not default constructor for the ArrayAdapter so it should be somthing like: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> itensAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,R.layout.list);

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

    if (id == DIALOG_PHONE_SELECT) {

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(CallBack.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, availablePhones);
        ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

you can use "android.R.layout.select_dialog_item" - dialog without OK button, or "android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice" with OK button